Help: G*Power Analysis for Correlation and Moderation
I have 3 measures, all scored on Likert style scales and I will be using the sum of items from each as scores. It is a cross-sectional study. predictor variable is attachment style (with two levels, anxious and avoidant), moderating variable is psychological stress (DASS-21), and the outcome variable is help-seeking attitudes (MHSAS). from the literature I expect a medium effect size.
I need to determine N value, number of participants:
Hypothesis 1 = Variable 1 is positively related to DV.
Hypothesis 2 = Variable 2 is negatively related to DV.
Hypothesis 3 = Variables 3 will moderate and strengthen correlations from H1 and H2.
Not sure which test to choose of G*Power?

Hi Cody. You probably need to give more details about your study. What is the context? Also note that in order to conduct a priori power analysis, you'll need to quantify much more precisely your hypotheses (e.g. "positively related", but by how much?).

hi, thanks for the reply. it is a cross-sectional study. predictor variable is attachment style (with two levels, anxious and avoidant), mediating variable is psychological stress (DASS-21), and the outcome variable is help-seeking attitudes (MHSAS). from the literature i expect a medium effect size.

Hi, the thing is - you are first (and in your comment) describing a mediation hypothesis, but in your middle paragraph you are describing a moderation hypothesis. It's important to know which you're going to test prior to power calculations.

Apologies all, I can see now my original questions was not very clear and I had confused some terms. I am seeking to do a moderation analysis but unsure of which test to use.

I can't answer now because the question is closed, but if you test your moderation hypothesis with a regression model with an interaction, you can use the r package InteractionPoweR for you power calculations. Check out this helpful article: https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/25152459231187531

There's also a Shiny app if you don't use R: https://mfinsaas.shinyapps.io/InteractionPoweR/

One more point - you say you expect a "medium" effect size but it's unclear for which predictor you expect this. Sounds like the interaction effect will be your target effect, because that tests the moderation hypothesis. However, interaction effects in psychology are notoriously small on average. So a power analysis in which you put in a medium sized regression coefficient for the interaction is probably not very realistic.

Thanks Sointu - that's a very helpful article. I have decided to go with ‘Linear multiple regression: Fixed model, R2 increase’ test (effect size f2 = .15, α err prob = .05, power = .80. Understand that the effect size may be lower however i have found literature with medium effect sizes associated to these constructs.


I'm sure f2 = .15 is a reasonable estimate for the main effects, but I'm fairly sure it will be way too large for the interaction. You should at least choose small effect size of f2=.02 if you want any chance of detecting an interaction effect. 2) your G*power choice does not adequately test for sample size for an interaction. Using it you can't model in the main effects or the correlation between your predictors, although they affect power and sample size.

